# Are there any performance difference regarding the depth level of a async/await in a sync method calling chain (c#)?

Tags: c#, async-await

Sorry if I didn't state my question clearly as system said this is a bad request missing problem clarification.

The problem (context) I hit is that I have some some synchronous APIs which will take a long time to finish as there are some network I/O involved. So, I am thinking how to improve the latency (and performance as well). This is a big question so I divide it into some sub questions and this thread will sever one such sub question regarding whether async/await could improve latency or not. I will use below example for my scenario.

I have an API (say FO1) which is synchronous, to fulfill its job, FO1 will call a method (FO2) which will call another method (FO3), and the total method calling chain is `FO1 -> FO2 -> FO3 ->... -> F9 -> F10`. F10 is an **asynchronous** method. So to call an async method in a sync context, I have to make a decision about where to stop the async/await propagation. So my question is: are there any differences (say latency or performance) between below chains (the methods in bold are async while the standard are sync):

1. FO1 -> FO2 -> FO3 ->... -> **F9 -> F10**
2. FO1 -> FO2 -> **FO3 ->... -> F9 -> F10**

I think from a client's perspective (callers of FO1), the latencies of above two should be very similar, but not sure which one is better?

Thanks

Comment: Every time you call `await` it has a to create an `IAsyncStateMachine` implementation, and as such has overhead (even though there is some caching), yet it probably pales in comparison to the IO call. However if this a hot path you can just elide (forward the task result) and not `await` in every method via `Task.FromResult`,  Just be sure to catch any method exceptions and add them to the returned task with `Task.FromException`

Comment: You can run a basic test using `BenchmarkDotNet`. I did a very quick benchmark, 1 and 2 perform almost exactly the same but 2 allocates ~2.5 times more `1189 B` vs `478 B`.

Comment: Also, if the async operation will frequently actually be synchronous: there are ways of avoiding the state machinery overhead, but it isn't automatic - it needs to be manually coded a little

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's practically no difference. As has been pointed out in the comments, the solution with more `async` methods will have more memory garbage and slightly slower execution, but both of these pale in comparison to the cost of I/O.

If FO1 will never be asynchronous, then I'd try to make the whole chain synchronous all the way. Why have anything asynchronous if it's just going to be blocked on?

Comment: thank you Stephen. As an API provider, we don't always have an optional solution, some APIs are indeed sync ones, but some of them do rely on some inner async 
implementations.